# Ansible Could not match host pattertn

Tags: ansible

I'm currently learnig Ansbible, I've followed a tutortial to install Wordpress on an VM on the cloud. The I have my project build like this :

```
[.]
|_ playbook.yml
|_ ansible.cfg
|_ inventori.ini
|_ [roles]
      |_ [server]
            |_ ...
      |_ [php]
            |_ ...
      |_ [mysql]
            |_ ...
      |_ [wordpress]
            |_ ... 
|_ [group_vars]
      |_ [web]
            |_ web.yml
|_ [host_vars]
      |_ vm1Devops.yml
```

When I'm running the command :

> ansible-playbook playbook.yml --ask-pass

I'm having the following error :

```
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not
match 'all'

[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Instead of sudo/sudo_user, use become/become_user and make sure become_method is 'sudo'
(default). This feature will be removed in version 2.9. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting
deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: {VMIP_HERE}


PLAY [{VMIP_HERE}] ***********************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************
```

I didn't understand what is happenig, Why ansible can catch my IP but tell me that the host list is empty ? Did I miss something ?

Here you can take a loot at my playbook.yml :

```
- hosts:
    - {VMIP_HERE}

  roles:
    - server
    - php
    - mysql
    - wordpress
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: I suspect your list of hosts is in `inventori.ini`.  If you lokk in `ansible.cfg`, you will see that `.ini` files are ignored.  Change the name to `inventory`, and you should be fine.

Comment: I've tried it doesn't work same error.

Comment: Can you post your `inventory` file?  I suspect the problem is there, not in your playbook.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible uses separate [inventory files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) or [dynamic inventory scripts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) or [dynamic inventory plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory.html) to know where to run the tasks found in a playbook.

The hosts line in a play is matched against an existing host group or individual host configured in the inventory file.

Try creating a separate inventory file and referencing it when calling your playbook.

```
$ cat '{VMIP_HERE}' >> inventory
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml --ask-pass
```

Additionally I do not believe that format for specifying the list of hosts in a play is supported.

Change

```
- hosts:
    - {VMIP_HERE}
```

to

```
- hosts: {VMIP_HERE}
```

If you want to run a play against a list of hosts or host groups you can separate them with colons ':'

```
- name: Run some tasks
  hosts: group_one:group_two:group_three
  gathers_facts: false
  become: false
  tasks:
  - name: Print hello world
    debug:
      msg: "Hello world"
```

Comment: That format for listing hosts and host groups is supported.